# Firefox SSL security warning

Tags: ssl, https

We have a weird issue on one of our sites.

The site in question forces https for all traffic but it throws a security error for some users. Different browsers, settings and network environments make it almost impossible to determine the cause of why the user is getting the error.

But, and here comes the question: when I try the same site on my machine, I get the security error in Firefox (v22) and not in Chrome or Safari, or in a VM running Windows 7 and IE9.

`www.domain.com uses an invalid security certificate.`

`The certificate is not trusted because no issuer chain was provided.`

`(Error code: sec_error_unknown_issuer)`

Is this an issue on the back-end and is Firefox the only browser failing because of it, or is it a problem in Firefox, thus making it a local browser problem?

Any feedback would be highly appreciated!

Comment: please check if this error comes with the sites having https(like gmail,odesk,facebook) and also tell me that ,its just case of firefox alone,the same websites working fine in other browsers?

Comment: Happens only for this site and the same site works fine in other browsers.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that you're including the certificate chain provided by the issuer?  Many issuers these days use intermediate certificates to establish the chain of trust back to the root CA.  Different browsers have different sets of CAs built in.

Check the instructions provided by your certificate issuer and make sure you're actually serving any intermediate certificates.